# gcloud deploy never finish with Updating service

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a python app to App Engine.
I've already deploy this app before but for some reason now it upload the files but then write `Updating service [default].../` and never finishes.

I'm using Windows 10 and all I can see after few minutes it is running is `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy)`.

The command I run is `gcloud app deploy --project my-proj -v 1 --quiet server/app.yaml`

I have the server side app in server sub directory.

Any ideas how to diagnose this problem?

**UPDATE1**
I've run the command with debug flag and I see this come every 5 seconds:

```
Updating service [default].../DEBUG: Received operation: [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e]

DEBUG: Operation [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e] not complete. Waiting 5s.

Updating service [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e] not complete. Waiting 5s.

Updating service [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e] not complete. Waiting 5s.

Updating service [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e] not complete. Waiting 5s.

DEBUG: Operation [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e] not complete. Waiting 5s.

Updating service [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/my-app/operations/b0647556-93af-4fd8-b0a7-f4ae43393e1e] not complete. Waiting 5s.
```

Comment: First of all, run the command without the `--quiet` flag and with `--verbosity=debug` to see if any useful error-related output is produced.

Comment: Same issue. Deploy takes for ever or never finishes.

Comment: Do you still have the issue??

Comment: I have the same problem....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, this was caused by software bug that was causing a 500 error - e.g. I believe during deploy App Engine does a simple health check to verify if the app has been successfully deployed, and if that fails it will loop forever.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so the solution for me was to deploy the app from console (https://console.cloud.google.com).
I cloned my git repo in the source code folder, after installing project, I run the command: gcloud app deploy --project [google-project-name]

Comment: that's suggest that GCP is broken

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me with the v2 endpoints. For backwards compatibility, I had added the old Servlet mapping of `_ah/spi` in my web.xml. This caused the application to get stuck at `Updating service [default]...` and never finish. It looks like just having the mapping for `_ah/api` works for backwards compatibility, so there must be some backend magic that is happening on the appengine side.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a new project in my case it was a flag

I had:

`"deploy": "gcloud app deploy --project quantified-self-io  --quiet --promote --stop-previous-version --version=v1 --verbosity=info",`

The flag `--stop-previous-version` was causing my issue since there was no prev version running I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. This is what I found out:

I followed @Daniel Hernandez's suggestion and uploaded the app from a cloned git repository inside cloud shell. It worked.

Then I went ahead and cloned that same repository that was working in cloud shell, but instead I cloned it into another folder in my computer. I deployed the app without any problem.

This made me suspicious so I started looking into what files were different from these two setups. I found out that in my original setup (the one that was failing) I had two extra folders:

```
env/
lib/
```

These correspond to the local development folders for virtualenv and the extra libraries. Note that these files were "ignored" from both `.gitignore` and the `skip_files` directive in `app.yaml`.

I deleted these two directories and tried to upload again and it worked.

Comment: I also saw a difference if I run `gcloud beta app deploy` or without **beta**. With beta, it would fail and without it would succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Gcloud SDK fixed the issue for me: `gcloud components update`

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428069/219657

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many different things that can cause this problem, so even though there is an already accepted answer in the OP's case I think it's worth documenting other possibilities on this question.

In my case it occurred because of pip's relatively new backtracking dependency resolver which, due to some underconstrained dependencies in my `requirements.txt` file, was causing pip to download many versions of some packages in order to determine the right dependencies.  This can be very slow and was causing the build to time out.  Better constraining my dependencies resolved the issue.

You can see what the build is doing in the Cloud Logs Explorer filtered by the "Cloud Build" resource type.  If there is a way to stream these logs via the CLI I'm not sure, but would love to be enlightened if so.

Answer (score 1):

Try seeing how many Mb, and if you have a weird file, for example, I had that error and I found a file that I have never seen