# Cannot deploy on App Engine with app engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using appcfg.py to update my app as usual, and I'm getting an error message. I've tried appcfg.py rollback, and I've waited ten minutes between attempts but I still get the same error message. What should I do?

cannot operate on apps/devnpfieldapp2/services/default/versions/1 because an operation is already in progress for 9866bb4e-75de-4a2a-a9f6-891ad7fe724e by 5a972249-5b35-45e0-abd1-ac3554ec425b.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to upgrade your Cloud SDK to the [latest version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) by running “gcloud components update” command and retry the upload. If the issue persists, you can report it to the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and provide us with the output of the command you are using to deploy your app with [“--noisy” flag](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments#globalopts-noisy) so that we would be able to dig into the issue.

It is also recommended to use [gcloud command Line equivalents](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud) to deploy apps since it is easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on CI but solved it by running the deploy command locally first, and then running it again on CI.

Comment: Running it again on CI doesn't tell us anything. What's different on CI than local?