# Debug Google App Engine deploy health check failure

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The context: running `gcloud app deploy` and seeing these errors every time:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.`

`(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back.`

From what I can tell, there's no good way to debug this. I've been shooting in the dark at this problem for the last several days. I've also read countless questions and answers related to this problem now. Does GCP offer any way to debug this? Or logs more detailed than, "it failed to become healthy"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some available options that you can use to further troubleshooting and debugging your application.

As indicated in the official documentation [Troubleshooting App Engine flexible deployment](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-aeflex-deployment), indicates that you can use one of the following two options, to further debugging your App Engine - including App Engine Standard, in case you are not using Flexible.

> 1. In the Google Cloud Console, SSH into your virtual machine. See connecting to an instance for more information.
> 2. Use a text viewer such as `tail`:
>
>    `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`

I believe these methods should help you with further options in trobleshooting and debugging your App Engine applications.

Besides that, this other documentation, might help you as well: [Viewing logs Classic](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: You can't SSH into a new instance before it passes the initial health check to finish deployment. I can get the new instance if I list the instances using gcloud, but then if I try to enable debug mode for the instance, I get `ABORTED: Cannot operate on ... because an operation is already in progress.` I get the same error if I try to ssh into it anyway. The other logs that I'm given elsewhere show everything up to once the Docker container is pushed. Then it's a black box where the health check is going on.

Comment: Hi @Jacquen thanks for confirming! Searching about this error that you mentioned now, as per a Google Support Engineer answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428069/12767257), it might be related to your Cloud SDK version. So, updating it, might be a good test. Anyway, it seems that they recommend you to reach out directly to them, for better troubleshooting. You can contact their support by using this link [here](https://cloud.google.com/support).